# Delete an Empty Group in Pandas Preserving the GroupBy Object

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get value_counts on a GroupBy object:

```
unstacked = data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="7D"))['domain'].value_counts().\
        sort_values(ascending=False).unstack().fillna(0)
```

Thus I get a nice DataFrame with domain values as columns and periods of time as rows and number of visits to a domain during a period in a corresponding cell. Cool.

However, once in a while I stumble upon an exception:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape (3,) (2,)
```

occuring in value_counts(). This was a strange behaviour in itself, but okay, trying to dig deeper, I found out that it happened when there was a group in the data with no items in it (for example, I group data over three 7-day intervals, and in the second interval there were just no entries).

```
>> grouped = data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="7D"))['domain']
>> grouped.head()
date
2017-04-01    google.com
2017-04-17    stackoverflow.com
Name: domain, dtype: object
>> print(grouped.groups)
{Timestamp('2017-04-15 00:00:00', freq='7D'): 2, Timestamp('2017-04-08 00:00:00', freq='7D'): 1, Timestamp('2017-04-01 00:00:00', freq='7D'): 1}
```

When I try to list the groups, I see the folowing exception:

```
>> for key, item in grouped:
>>    print(key)
>>    print(grouped.get_group(key))
date
2017-04-01    google.com
Name: domain, dtype: object
2017-04-08 00:00:00
KeyError: Timestamp('2017-04-08 00:00:00', freq='7D')
```

For me it seems that the valid solution would be to delete the group designated as `Timestamp('2017-04-08 00:00:00', freq='7D')` from the SeriesGroupBy while preserving the object itself. However, this seems to be impossible (methods like using `filter` return a DataFrame, and good old `del` also gives an exception).

Could anyone propose a workaround for this task? I think I have tried almost anything.

Mini-data:

```
date,domain
2017-04-01,google.com
2017-04-17,stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: try using `resample` instead of `groupby`.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer, Paul. However, I am still getting that `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape (3,) (2,)`

Comment: can you post some data that reproduces this issue?

Comment: The csv goes as follows:

Comment: Your data didn't post and it wouldn't belong in comments anyway. Edit the question to include all relevant information.

Comment: Paul, thank you for the attention to my problem :) The data was added at the same time as the comment right at the bottom of the post.