# How can I ignore empty series when using value_counts on a Pandas groupby?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've got a DataFrame with the metadata for a newspaper article in each row. I'd like to group these into monthly chunks, then count the values of one column (called `type`):

```
monthly_articles = articles.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M"))
monthly_articles = monthly_articles["type"].value_counts().unstack()
```

This works fine with an annual group but fails when I try to group by month:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape (141,) (139,)
```

I think this is because there are some month groups in which there are no articles. If I iterate the groups and print value_counts on each group:

```
for name, group in monthly_articles:
    print(name, group["type"].value_counts())
```

I get empty series in the groups for Jan and Feb of 2006:

```
2005-12-31 00:00:00 positive    1
Name: type, dtype: int64
2006-01-31 00:00:00 Series([], Name: type, dtype: int64)
2006-02-28 00:00:00 Series([], Name: type, dtype: int64)
2006-03-31 00:00:00 negative    6
positive    5
neutral     1
Name: type, dtype: int64
2006-04-30 00:00:00 negative    11
positive     6
neutral      3
Name: type, dtype: int64
```

How can I ignore the empty groups when using `value_counts()`?

I've tried `dropna=False` without success. I think this is the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763256/delete-an-empty-group-in-pandas-preserving-the-groupby-object).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd better give us data sample. Otherwise, it is a little hard to point out the problem. From your code snippet, it seems that the `type` data for some months is null. You can use `apply` function on grouped objects and then call `unstack` function. Here is the sample code that works for me, and the data is randomly generated

```
s = pd.Series(['positive', 'negtive', 'neutral'], index=[0, 1, 2])
atype = s.loc[np.random.randint(3, size=(150,))]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(atype=atype.values), index=pd.date_range('2017-01-01',  periods=150))

gp = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))
dfx = gp.apply(lambda g: g['atype'].value_counts()).unstack()

In [75]: dfx
Out[75]: 
            negtive  neutral  positive
2017-01-31       13        9         9
2017-02-28       11       11         6
2017-03-31       12        6        13
2017-04-30        8       12        10
2017-05-31        9       10        11
```

In case there are null values:

```
In [76]: df.loc['2017-02-01':'2017-04-01', 'atype'] = np.nan
    ...: gp = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))
    ...: dfx = gp.apply(lambda g: g['atype'].value_counts()).unstack()
    ...: 

In [77]: dfx
Out[77]: 
            negtive  neutral  positive
2017-01-31       13        9         9
2017-04-30        8       12         9
2017-05-31        9       10        11
```

Thanks.