# How to sovle >ValueError< with pandas Series and python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

I'm using **python** (3.7.4) together with **pandas** (0.25.0) and want to use `value_counts()` on a Series.

While executing the statement i get a **ValueError**.

Any suggestions to sovle this error?

```
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series([1, 2], index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-09-22', '2019-09-24']))
series.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).value_counts()
```

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1244, in value_counts
    labels = list(map(rep, self.grouper.recons_labels)) + [llab(lab, inc)]
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in repeat
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 481, in repeat
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'repeat', repeats, axis=axis)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 61, in _wrapfunc
    return bound(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape (3,) (2,)
```

Python:

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul 16 2019, 07:12:58) 
[GCC 9.1.0] on linux
```

**EDIT**:

NOTE: The given data is only test data to reproduce the error.

For some reasons a changed dataset works fine:

```
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series([1, 2], index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-09-22', '2019-09-23']))
series.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).value_counts()
2019-09-22  1    1
2019-09-23  2    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is from applying `.value_counts()` to the empty series that is created when you resample your index using the `Grouper`.

You can see this by viewing the groups in your example:

```py
for n,g in series.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')):
    print(n,'\n', g, '\n')

2019-09-22 00:00:00
 2019-09-22    1
dtype: int64

2019-09-23 00:00:00
 Series([], dtype: int64)

2019-09-24 00:00:00
 2019-09-24    2
dtype: int64
```

To avoid passing the empty series to the `.value_counts()` method, use `.apply()` on the groupby object as pointed out in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45805110/7517724.

For your case, the code should be:

```py
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series([1, 2], index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-09-22', '2019-09-24']))
series.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).apply(lambda g: g.value_counts())
```

which produces:

```py
2019-09-22  1    1
2019-09-24  2    1
dtype: int64
```

Another option is to avoid the resampling and instead cast your index to the periods that you are interested in using the `.to_period()` method on the DateTime index:

```py
series.groupby(series.index.to_period(freq='D')).value_counts()
```

which produces the same output as the `.apply()` example.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access the value of `series.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))` you wont get a Series but a SeriesGroupBy object.

Try this instead: `series.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).first().value_counts()`